# 422 error on patch request from react to rails

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, axios

I have a switch that toggles a boolean in my database. For whatever reason I am getting a 422 response from the PATCH request. The function initially triggering the request is:

```
const handleChange = (game) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_GAME', payload: { id: game.id, own: !game.own }})
}
```

The saga function making the request when that switch is clicked is:

```
    function* updateGame(action) {
      try {
        yield axios.patch(`/api/v1/games/update/${action.payload.id}`, action.payload)
        yield put({ type: 'FETCH_GAMES' })
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error updating game", err)
      }
    }
```

And my routes file in rails is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      get 'games/index'
      post 'games/create'
      patch 'games/update/:id', to: 'games#update'
      delete 'games/:id', to: 'games#destroy'
      get 'genres/index'
      post 'genres/create'
      delete 'genres/:id', to: 'genres#destroy'
    end
  end

  root 'pages#home'
end
```

I have also tried sending the request and a POST request in postman and am getting the same 422 error. GET requests work fine.

EDIT:
Here's my game_controller.rb:

```
class Api::V1::GamesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_game, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @games = Game.all.order(title: :asc)
    render json: @games
  end

  def show
    if @game
      render json: @game
    else
      render json: @game.errors
    end
  end

  def new
    @game = Game.new
  end

  def edit
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)

    if @game.save
      render json: @game
    else
      render json: @game.errors
    end
  end

  def update
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])

    if @game.update(game_params)
      redirect_to @game
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @game.destroy

    render json: { notice: 'Game was successfully removed.' }
  end

  private
    def set_game
      @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    end

    def game_params
      params.permit(:title, :own, :image_url, :genre_id)
    end
end
```

EDIT 2:

I added

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

to my GameControler after realizing I was getting a CSRF token authorization error. Now I can make some PATCH requests. For some reason I'm getting

```
03:01:43 web.1 | Unpermitted parameter: :game. Context: { 
controller: Api::V1::GamesController, action: update, request: #. 
<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00000001095901f0>, params: {"id"=>"1", 
"own"=>false, "controller"=>"api/v1/games", "action"=>"update", 
"game"=>{"id"=>"1", "own"=>false}} }
```

in the server console whenever the value is set to false. Any other changes seem to work.

Comment: Add your GamesController. What exact errors are you getting? Is there anything relevant in the server logs?

Comment: I updated the original post. The most relevant thing I can find in the log is:

02:42:05 web.1  | Started PATCH "/api/v1/games/update/1" for ::1 at 2023-06-28 02:42:05 -0500
02:42:05 web.1  | Processing by Api::V1::GamesController#update as HTML
02:42:05 web.1  |   Parameters: {"id"=>"1", "own"=>false, "game"=>{"id"=>"1", "own"=>false}}
02:42:05 web.1  | Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
02:42:05 web.1  | Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 488)

There is a lot more but that seems to be where it makes and rejects the patch request.

Comment: I'll admit it's probably something in the controller because I understand that file the least. I tried doing something similar to what I read in a tutorial and adapt it to my app.

Comment: I tried adding 'protect_from_forgery with: :null_session' to ignore the CSRF error but now I get: 03:01:43 web.1  | Unpermitted parameter: :game. Context: { controller: Api::V1::GamesController, action: update, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00000001095901f0>, params: {"id"=>"1", "own"=>false, "controller"=>"api/v1/games", "action"=>"update", "game"=>{"id"=>"1", "own"=>false}} }

Comment: Ok I've narrowed it down to something specifically when the boolean is false. I can update other things including changing the boolean field to true.

Comment: Add relevant info to the question- not in comments. Comments are not permanent.